# Searchview for intentable buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I'm working on an android project. I have created an activity with `RelativeLayout` having multiple buttons row by row.`Buttons` are intent on their respective layout.I have to add a search option to the same activity for search button according to the text.

`Activity_main.xml` :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:text="pizza"
        android:background="#6b6868"
        android:textColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:text="burger"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
        android:text="roll"
        android:background="#6b6868"
        android:textColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
```

`Mainactivity.java :`

```
public class Bus extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus);

    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.pizza);
            Intent MyIntent = getIntent();
        }
    });
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.burger);
            Intent MyIntent = getIntent();
        }
        });
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.roll);
            Intent MyIntent = getIntent();
        }
    });
```

Now I have to add a search option to this multiple button list
ie.I wanna search and intent both.

please share full code that I can implement directly because I'm new to android

Comment: It will be better if you use a custom Listview. And you can add a filter to search.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question is too broad to answer for the format of this site. SO is for help with specific issues - questions like "Please implement search for my app" are out of scope here.

Comment: What is the content for searching , maybe text on button ? Q is ok not  too broad .